# salesforce docusign status didn't create after siging

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have a question about Salesforce integrated with Docusign, when I signed a envelope, it should has a docusign status record, but it didn't. I don't know it's that a configuration problem or it's about my code problem. Did anybody has the same issue?

Thanks
Stefan

Comment: It sounds like a configuration issue. Please contact DocuSign Customer Support for assistance. StackOverflow is used only for help with issues with programming code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer from DocuSign community forum:
https://community.docusign.com/t5/DocuSign-for-Salesforce/Salesforce-Troubleshooting/td-p/2485

If you are receiving an error message when using DocuSign for Salesforce here are some steps you may take to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Administrator to check from the DocuSign console:

   > Preferences >Connect
   >   Is Login Configured? If not Configure Login
   >   Are Items Selected in “System Settings” and “Sender Selectable Items”?
   >   Is User integrated? We would recommend “All users integrated”, this way you do not have to make sure this is completed when activating an individual User in SF
2. Within Salesforce:
   Salesforce Administrator to verify that DSFSF has been Deployed>
   Setup > View Installed Packages > DocuSign for Salesforce I
   Is Deploy button gray’d out? If not Deploy package and try to send again
3. Salesforce Administrator to check the User Profile, double check user has access to DocuSign
4. Verify User’s DocuSign password has been encrypted

Do you know your DS password? log into DS account with email and password, if your password does not work, request a password reset from DocuSign

Once you create your Docusign Password you will need to update Salesforce, follow these steps: 
1) Log in to SalesForce
2) Clicking on the {DocuSignAdmin} tab.
3) Click on the green {Administration} tab
4) Click on the button that allows the individual to enter their docusign password
5) Type in that new password and click the button to save

5. User to verify Network access: Setup > Administration Setup > Network Access > Trusted IP Address, if blank input 209.67.98.12

If you are still experiencing an error with DS4SF after running through all troubleshooting steps you will need to contact Customer Support.  Please Contact Us and we would be happy to investigate further :smileyhappy:
**You can reference this community post so you don't have to re-explain the issue.

We can then set up a Go To Meeting and view your screen to help resolve your issue.

Additionally, you may find our DocuSign for Salesforce guides useful. You can view those here: User Guides